# How to make first element(s) available on center-aligned flex items

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

When using center-aligned flexbox first elements gets hidden and inavailable in scrollbar on smaller viewport.

Example, shrink to small VP and first element gets hidden:
https://codepen.io/tomjoad2000/pen/xoaKrg

Tested in both FF and Chrome.
Is there any fix without manually tweeking the smaller viewport?

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .chaptersContainer {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: flex-start;
            overflow-x: auto;
            border: 1px solid #900;
        }



        .chapter {
            display: block;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            width: 10em;
            height: 10em;
        }

        .chapter h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="chaptersContainer">
        <div class="chapter">
            <h2>first</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">
            <h2>asdf</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">
            <h2>asdf</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">
            <h2>asdf</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">
            <h2>asdf</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="chapter">
            <h2>last</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any reason as to why not changing into: `justify-content: left;`?

Comment: Ah sorry, they need to be centered on larger view-ports